# How to dump the bytecode of an ASM generated class?

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode

I am tackling an issue with regards to code generation with parboiled ([link to the issue](https://github.com/parboiled1/parboiled-core/issues/1)).

The problem is that the bug seems to be not in the `Parser` class itself but in the bytecode generated by parboiled for its rules and one in particular, as the beginning of the stacktrace seems to indicate:

```
at org.parboiled.matchers.ProxyMatcher.label(ProxyMatcher.java:156)
at repro.abc.Parser$$parboiled.R33(Unknown Source)
at repro.abc.Parser.R32(Parser.java:239)
at repro.abc.Parser$$parboiled.R32(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is in that `R33` method of the generated `repro.abc.Parser$$parboiled` class. And I can't find a way to dump it :(

I can `.getResourceAsStream("/repro/abc/Parser.class")` without a problem, but of course it does not contain the code which interests me, which is generated by `Parboiled.createParser()`.

How do I access/dump this bytecode to a file?

EDIT: OK, to be more precise, when you do:

```
Parser<?> parser = Parboiled.createParser(Parser.class);
```

`parser` is of type `Parser$$parboiled`. I have tried to `.getClass()` but I can't get an `InputStream` :(

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using a tool that modifies classfiles at runtime and you're trying to figure out how to dump the modified classfile? Why not just hook ClassLoader.defineClass?

Comment: @Antimony it's not that simple; I only wish to access this inner `$$` class. I can dump `Parser` but that does not interest me here

Comment: Well, if you could somehow catch the bytes and write them out to a file you could use `javap`.  Otherwise the JDI defines runtime interfaces to get at the bytecodes, but I've never tried to use it.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, I've been struggling for quite a while now :( I have even tried to create an ASM `ClassReader` but to no avail.

Comment: If you can get the bytes, I have the source for a crude (& flaky) class file parser, written in Java.

Comment: @HotLicks I did get them... `javap -c` works on what I could obtain. I'd happily lay my hands on anything that can help me at this point!

Answer (score 0):

OK well, I have found a solution but it is really hackish...

The solution is to add a method to write the generated class' byte code into a file in `ParserTransformer#defineExtendedParserClass()`...

But I'd have really appreciated a less hackish solution :/

Comment: Hooking ClassLoader.defineClass would likely work too. I'm not sure if you'd consider that more or less hackish.

Comment: @Antimony meh, I have just started volunteering maintaining this project and have never 1. touched ASM or 2. done such advanced classloading before, so at this moment I cannot even understand what you are talking about ;) But I'm learning, slowly...